# Selecting Data Items dynamically for logging application - Database / XML / Other?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I am working on an application that communicates with an embedded device to log or view data from networked machinery. The machinery is networked and communicates with data logging device via CAN (ISO 15765-4). The logging device uses an unmanaged DLL API, which I have already created a working Wrapper - and I can send single hard coded requests to the logger and properly parse the data (With the help of this website) - I do not need help with wrapping the dll, parsing CAN, or communication with the logging device, that is all working. What I am needing help with is an overall strategy for setting up the individual data items to be logged - through a database, xml serialization, or have the data embedded within the code. My thoughts are a database would be ideal for this but I am struggling on how to implement this in a good OOP strategy.

The next step is to allow user to dynamically select the data they wish to view / log, and have the application setup the requests / responses dynamically. The application that my company is currently using for this function is all in c++, and it is extremely buggy and hard to maintain as the original coding team has moved on. I am NOT trying to directly port the c++ code or structure to C#, just the functionality. I am providing some snippets of the c++ code just as an example of the type of data I am trying to work with. I am using C# because of the relative ease for creating a GUI compared to c++.

The data being logged can be 1 of 3 different types:

1. Boolean (true / false)
2. Linear (y=mx+b)
3. Switched enumerations (1 = Cold, 2 = Warm, 3 = Hot, 4 = Overheated)

Here are some general requirements for the application

- There are approximately 400 unique data items that can be logged.
- Typically, there will be between 20 - 50 items monitored at any one time, but the capability needs to exist to log ALL supported data.
- Not all of the machinery supports all data items - so there is a pruning request to determine what is supported by each machine.
- CAN requests are FUNCTIONAL addressing rather than PHYSICAL addressing - so requests are made with a broadcast type message, and all supporting equipment will respond. (This just means I may get multiple responses from the same request)
- Data should be able to be viewed live - or logged to file for later analysis. Any saved logs would be on the order of 10,000 frames (probably never exceeding 50,000 frames)
- Typical request / response turn around is ~150mS, with each request occurring in a sequential manner (must repeat each request in a loop)

So here is a typical use case:

1. User connects application to embedded device
2. Query all connected machinery for supported data
3. Present user with a list of supported data
4. User selects data from this set to log/display
5. "Stream" data to GUI in text or graphical format with option to save
6. View saved data (without embedded device connected)

I have all of the potential supported data items in an excel table currently with the thought that I could port it in to a database or xml file. Although this data is not "Top Secret", we would like to hide/encrypt it from customers/end users if possible (although I can work on that later - just bringing the point up now in case it changes the strategy)

I have been searching the web over the last couple of weeks, and I am just hitting a mental block on how to deal with this. Do I read the data list from database and create a class that houses all of the parameters? Do I create a separate class for each data item? Structure? etc? I just cant quite figure out the strategy to get me started. I am not looking for someone to do this for me, just a direction to go (small code examples would be helpful as a starting point however) I know that I will need to use threading to keep the GUI updated, so if this factors in to any strategy as well. Once the initial setup is made, it is basically an infinite loop until user cancels the action or there is a predefined trigger to halt the data flow. I know that this will tie up the GUI so a background thread will be needed to keep screen refreshed and responsive.

Below is a snippet from the c++ code -all of the data was embedded within the code, any changes that needed to be made (add or edit existing data items) required changes in about 4 different places, so it is extremely hard to maintain. This is just an example - 1 of each type of data, along with how they structured things. Basically they had a struct like block for each data item, and an enumeration that contained ALL data items. Any switch cases had separate code that defined the states. I am thinking this would be much better suited to a database than 20000 lines of code strictly dealing with the data item values / conversions / text, etc (That is how much c++ code is devoted to this)

Thanks in advance for any help or direction you can give

-Lee

```
// Example of a Switch Case enumerated data item
ITEMs::PARAM ITEMs::m_CASE_A =
{
    0,          // starting byte
    0,          // ending byte
    0,          // starting bit
    4,          // ending bit
    1,          // number of bytes
    5,          // number of bits
    {
        _T("Long Description Case A"),                    // Full description
        _T("Case A"),                                     // Abbreviated description
        _T("CASEA"),                                      //  acronym 1
        _T("CASEA"),                                      //  acronym 2
        DATA_TYPE_INTEGER,                                // Data type
        0x03,                                             // DATA Itentifier
        UOM_ENUMERATION,                                  // Raw units to be scaled
        UOM_ENUMERATION,                                  // Default units of measure for display
        0.0,                                              // Minimum value for numeric types
        FALSE,                                            // TRUE if minimum value defined
        0.0,                                              // Maximum value for numeric types
        FALSE,                                            // TRUE if maximum value defined
        -0.5,                                             // Minimum display value
        6.5,                                              // Maximum display value
        0.0,                                              // Tolerance
        FALSE,                                            // TRUE if tolerance defined
        0,                                                // Number of digits after decimal pt
        NUMERIC_FORMAT_DECIMAL,                           // Default format for numeric types
        0.0,                                              // Scaling per bit
        0.0,                                              // Bias to apply after scaling
        FALSE,                                            // TRUE if signed for numeric types
        _T(""),                                           // String to display when boolean parameter is ON
        _T(""),                                           // String to display when boolean parameter is OFF
        _T(""),                                           // String to display when numeric value is not valid
        TRUE                                              // Visible to end-user
    }
};


// Example of a Linear Data Items
ITEMs::PARAM ITEMs::m_LINEAR_A =
{
    0,          // starting byte
    0,          // ending byte
    0,          // starting bit
    7,          // ending bit
    1,          // number of bytes
    8,          // number of bits
    {
        _T("Long  Description Linear A"),                 // Full description
        _T("LINEAR A"),                                    // Abbreviated description
        _T("LIN_A"),                                        // acronym
        _T("LIN_A"),                                        // acronym
        DATA_TYPE_FLOAT,                                  // Data type
        0x05,                                             // DATA Itentifier
        UOM_TEMP_DEGC,                                    // Raw units to be scaled
        UOM_TEMP_DEGF,                                    // Default units of measure for display
        -40.0,                                            // Minimum value for numeric types
        TRUE,                                             // TRUE if minimum value defined
        215.0,                                            // Maximum value for numeric types
        TRUE,                                             // TRUE if maximum value defined
        -40.0,                                            // Minimum display value
        419.0,                                            // Maximum display value
        9.0,                                              // Tolerance
        TRUE,                                             // TRUE if tolerance defined
        0,                                                // Number of digits after decimal pt
        NUMERIC_FORMAT_DECIMAL,                           // Default format for numeric types
        1.8,                                              // Scaling per bit
        -40.0,                                            // Bias to apply after scaling
        FALSE,                                            // TRUE if signed for numeric types
        _T(""),                                           // String to display when boolean parameter is ON
        _T(""),                                           // String to display when boolean parameter is OFF
        _T(""),                                           // String to display when numeric value is not valid
        TRUE                                              // Visible to end-user
    }
};


// Example of a Boolean Data Item
ITEMs::PARAM ITEMs::m_BOOL_A =
{
    1,          // starting byte
    1,          // ending byte
    6,          // starting bit
    6,          // ending bit
    1,          // number of bytes
    1,          // number of bits
    {
        _T("Long Description BOOL A"),                    // Full description
        _T("Boolean A"),                                  // Abbreviated description
        _T("BOOL_A"),                                     // acronym
        _T("BOOL_A"),                                     // acronym
        DATA_TYPE_BOOLEAN,                                // Data type
        0x01,                                             // DATA Itentifier
        UOM_NONE,                                         // Raw units to be scaled
        UOM_NONE,                                         // Default units of measure for display
        0.0,                                              // Minimum value for numeric types
        FALSE,                                            // TRUE if minimum value defined
        0.0,                                              // Maximum value for numeric types
        FALSE,                                            // TRUE if maximum value defined
        0.0,                                              // Minimum display value
        0.0,                                              // Maximum display value
        0.0,                                              // Tolerance
        FALSE,                                            // TRUE if tolerance defined
        0,                                                // Number of digits after decimal pt
        NUMERIC_FORMAT_NONE,                              // Default format for numeric types
        1.0,                                              // Scaling per bit
        0.0,                                              // Bias to apply after scaling
        FALSE,                                            // TRUE if signed for numeric types
        _T("NO"),                                         // String to display when boolean parameter is 1
        _T("YES"),                                        // String to display when boolean parameter is 0
        _T(""),                                           // String to display when numeric value is not valid
        TRUE                                              // Visible to end-user
    }
};



// This example sets the user display text for enumerated CASE data items (m_CASE_A in example above)
void PARAM1::FormatValue( ULONG value, 
                                    CStdString* pstrResult,
                                    PARAMVALUETYPE* pdResult )
{
    UINT uID;
    UCHAR uValue = value & 0xFF;
    *pdResult = (PARAMVALUETYPE)uValue;

    if ( pstrResult != NULL )
    {
        switch ( uValue )
        {
            case 0x01: uID = CASE_1; break;
            case 0x02: uID = CASE_2; break;
            case 0x03: uID = CASE_3; break;
            default: uID = CASE_INVALID; break;
        }

        (*pstrResult).LoadString( uID );
    }
}



// CAUTION: Items must be in same order as in the enumeration DATA_ENUM.
ITEMs::PARAM* ITEMs::m_PARAMs[] =
    {
        &m_CASE_A,
        &m_LINEAR_A,
        &m_BOOL_A,
        ...
        ...
        ...
    };


// Enumeration of all Data Parameters
    typedef enum
    {
        CASE_A,     
        LINEAR_A, 
        BOOL_A, 
        ...
        ...
        ...
    } DATA_ENUM;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, although I do not understand all the details (for example, how actually this log data is gathered, I believe this is based on cyclic request/response pattern) I have some design thoughts about it:

- whether *metadata* about data items should be stored in database or XML depends how often it will change and what is distribution model of this software. If it is internal application used by a few people in your company, probably storing local configuration (in XML file for example) will be enough. If the number of users is big, synchronization and management through database will be useful. If it is a application sold to users, it would be in place to have some auto-updates system, so here we come back to the file solution again. Personally I would choose to use a configuration file because it covers more scenarios and it would be probably a XML file due to its clearness.
- I would choose to represent each data item as a instance of some subclass (`EnumDataItem`, `LinearDataItem`, ...) of abstract `DataItem` class (or just `IDataItem` interface). They should implement methods like `Serialize`/`Deserialize` (for request/response manipulation) and `Format` (or `ToString` simply) for GUI/logging. Definitions of those data items should be loaded from XML file. Then you can define a `Parameters` class that is a list of `IDataItem`s and can be easily `Serialized`/`Deserialized`.
- I have a feeling (although it might be wrong) that there can be a lot of similar data items, so I would think about possibility of *templating* or *deriving*, so I could specify in XML some templates that can be reused in defining concrete data items.

Comment: Thank You, that is exactly the type of information I was looking for. This application MAY be marketed to customers, but the data stored in the xml/database would be read-only, and would vary rarely change. You are correct in your assumption that there are many similar data items, so I will look into templates for the xml. I am going to mark this as the accepted answer. Again - thanks for your insight